# How to make the text in center in the cells of JSPDF

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, jspdf

Hello I am using JSPDF for generating the PDF manually through creating cells.

I have to assign the height of the cells but when the size of the text is more then it over laps the cells. How can I avoid that.

[image]

Here is my code :

```
           var l = {
                    orientation: 'l',
                    unit: 'mm',
                    format: 'a4',
                    compress: true,
                    fontSize: 8,
                    lineHeight: 1,
                    autoSize: false,
                    printHeaders: true
                }, pdf = new jsPDF(l, '', '', ''), i, j, margins = {
                    top: 30,
                    bottom: 10,
                    left: 10,
                    width: 25
                };

                //initializing the cells
                pdf.cellInitialize();

                var lines = pdf.splitTextToSize(' This is large icon to f', 12);
                pdf.cell(margins.left, margins.top, 14, 8, lines, 0);

                pdf.save('Te.pdf');
```

Now I can increase the height of the cells but the text still over laps the cells.

Here is how it looks like.

[image]

Can anyone help me. I am using JSPDF https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use JSPDF for this?

You could easily achieve what you need in pdfmake (http://pdfmake.org).

The philosophy is a little bit different though - pdfmake is a declarative library which calculates layout automatically.

Basic table definition looks like this:

```
var docDefinition = {
  content: [
    {
      table: {
        // header rows are automatically repeated if the table spans over multiple pages
        // you can declare how many rows should be treated as headers
        headerRows: 1,
        widths: [ '*', 'auto', 100, '*' ],

        body: [
          [ 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'The last one' ],
          [ 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4' ],
          [ { text: 'Bold value', bold: true }, 'Val 2', 'Val 3', 'Val 4' ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

There's also support for col/row spans, unbreakable rows (in case there's not enough space left on current page), auto-sized, fixed-sized and star-sized columns.

You could check the the table example in [pdfmake playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html)

Comment: I have even looked at the pdfmake but it does not provide any documentation nor does it specify that it will support IE8+

Comment: currently most options are described in [getting started](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted)... IE8 - I'll have to think about it ;)

Comment: Thanks :) IE8 is the biggest problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suffered from the same issue.

But if you take a look at the jspdf.plugin.cell.js, it's actually drawing a rectangle which wraps text in. In other words, the cell itself is a rectangle.

Inside of the 
    `jsPDFAPI.cell()` function,
    `this.text(txt, x + 3, y + h - 3);`,
this line actually controls where the text will appear in side of each cell.

You can do something like this:
    `this.text(txt, x + 3, y + h/2 - 3);`, then the text will be centered in a cell.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I already fix the issue long before by making some changes to the base library of JSPDF.